# Force EmptyView to display?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a `ListView` that I am creating. The content is set from a separate adapter class. When the adapter returns zero items I want the empty view to display from a separate xml. This is happening inside a `SherlockFragment`. However for some reason I cannot get the `emptyView` to display.

Help Please?

Code:

```
    RelativeLayout fragView = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        listView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.emptyView));//This is having no effect
        scoreViewAdapter = new ScoreViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                databaseHelper.getAllTimeRecords());
        listView.setAdapter(scoreViewAdapter);
        if (scoreViewAdapter.getCount() < 1)
                  listView.//can I set something here to force or change my view? From the methods available to ListView I don't see any potential solutions..
        fragView.addView(listView);
```

Here is the xml....pretty standard.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/emptyView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emptyText"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_android_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="No Items Found"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Thanks to Faizan's feedback to lead me here. Here is the solution:

```
    View empty_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null);
    ...
    if (scoreViewAdapter.getCount() < 1)
         fragView.addView(empty_view);
    fragView.addView(listView);
```

Comment: Where is this R.id.emptyView come from??? share the xml

Comment: added the xml...just a standard empty view implementation. It works elsewhere in my application in other ListViews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inflate that xml using `LayoutInflater` and then call

```
listView.setEmptyView(inflated_view);
```

You can get get the inflater from the `onCreateView` overrided method anc do

```
View inflated_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_empty_layout,null);
```

I hope it will resolve the problem.

Comment: The .setEmptyView(); method still seems to not have an effect, however this did lead me to a working solution. See my edit for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you extends `FragmentList` and not `ListActivity` 
so you actually can use [setEmptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: I added the fragView initialization..this is all happening inside a RelativeLayout therefore I am exntending a SherlockFragment vs SherlockListFragment